# Tesseract unable to read math expression

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tesseract

I got this image of a simple math expression Tesseract fails to read:

[image: 8 - 3 = 5]

I've tested a screenshot of the same expression written on an Android phone and it was read pretty well. So I thought it's a font problem.
I considered:

- Preprocess the image by inverting or removing the red areas
- [Training Tesseract with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352918/how-do-i-train-tesseract-4-with-image-data-instead-of-a-font-file) (StackOverflow question with no answers)
- Using [WhatFontIs.com](https://www.whatfontis.com/) to find similar font then training Tesseract with the font file with [TrainYourTesseract](http://trainyourtesseract.com/)

Answer (score 1):

But as I was typing the question, I looked around for more.

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39328235/4385565) prompted me to double check my sanity with this [VietOCR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vietocr/) software which outputs `8-3`, close enough!

Then I messed around the software and found that I could pass `--psm 7` `(Page Segmentation Mode 7: Treat the image as a single text line)` to my script, which works well for my math expressions:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 7')
```

[List of PSMs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632770/4385565)